# How to read from a file and then analyze this data?

Tags: java, variables, methods, bufferedreader

I am a begginer(recently began learning) at programming in Java and I need help.

I have to read from a file, which contains numbers. I would like to make a method for reading from a file. Then I need to analyze this data and write it in another file.

What I strugle with is if I make a method just to read from a file or do I also have to save this read data into a variable. Where should this variable be declared inside a method (if is inside, how do I use it outside), if is outside how do I use it inside a method and also outside. Can anyone help me clarify this? What am I doing wrong?

My code of what I wrote until now. File from which I had to read has houndreds of numbers.

```java
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nameFile = "numbers.txt";
        File file = new File(nameFile);
        String contentFile ="";

    }

    //Method for reading a .txt file
    private static String readFromFile(String nameFile, String contentFile) {

        String line = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));

            while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                    line = contentFIle;
            }
            read.close();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading from a file");
    } 
        return line;
    }

}
```

Comment: a) you need to call the method that you wrote b) the method return a single String, so this can be assigned to a variable in your main method `String stuff = readFromFile(.....);`  c) as you are looping, maybe appended to `line` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically speaking: mathematical functions get input variables, they preform some transformation on the variables and output the result of the transformation.

For example: `f(x) = x - 1`, `g(x) = x * 2`
You can chain functions in a way that one functions output will be the other function input: `g(f(2))`. In this case, the number 2 is used as an input for function `f(x)` and the output of `f(x)` is the input of `g(x)`.

Functions and methods in programming **can** work in a similar way, but It may be more readable to save function output into meaningful variable names, and then to apply these variables to the next function.

Instead of doing: `outputText(processText(readText(someFilename)))`
You can write (pseudocode):

```
someFilename = 'foo'
text = readText(someFilename)
processed = processText(text)
outputText(processed)
```

In java and in your context this would look like the following:

```java
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nameFile = "numbers.txt";
        String contentFile = readFromFileByName(nameFile);
        String altered = processText(contentFile);
        saveToFile(altered, "processed.txt");
    }


    private static String readFromFileByName(String nameFile) {
        String fullRead = "";
        try {
            File file = new File(nameFile);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line; // define line variable
            while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                    fullRead += line; // pay attention for the altered code
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error reading from a file");
        } finally {
            return fullRead;
        }
    }

    private static List<Integer> stringToIntList(String string) {
        return Arrays
            .stream(text.split(", "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static String processText(String text) {
        String processed = text.replace('H', 'h'); // Some heavy processing :)
        return processed;
    }

    private static void saveToFile(String text, String fileName) {
        // save <text> to file with filename <filename>
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it and it works. Just can't figure out where did you initialize variable: line? Or it does program by itself.

Comment: @Escape sorry, I didn't define It earlier as I should have. Now edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. I have another question :) 
How do I processText if text are numbers?

Comment: Ive added an example `stringToIntList` function. In case your integers are comma and space separated, this method allows you to parse them into `List<Integer>` and then you can do any operations on them.

Comment: sorry for asking again, I still didnt complete this :) I have a problem when I try to pritn out all numbers that are prime numbers and numbers that can only be devided by 3, 5 or 11. I have a txt file, with numbers in 10.000 lines, with approximately 20 numbers in a line. I then also have to make a sum of numbers in each line. What woul you suggest for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) `Line` is the variable that you have read to. So you shouldn't change its value.

```
line = contentFIle;
```

if you need only first line this method should look like:

```
 private static String readFromFile(String nameFile) {

    String line = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));

        line = read.readLine();
        read.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There was an error reading from a file");
} 
    return line;
}
```

if you need a list of this:

```
List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList(); 
try { 
  Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
  // do something 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
return lines;
```

2) Also you don't call readFromFile function. So you need to change the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nameFile = "numbers.txt";
    String contentFile = readFromFile(nameFile);

}
```

3)For your particular case, there's no sense to call readFromFile with `String contentFile` because you don't use this variable.

Comment: Thanks! I need a list of this, because later I have to count sum for each row. So I suppose this: List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();  should be a good option. Does this save numbers like they are in the file or it stores all in the same line. And what if I just want to read line by line?